# How do I use a regex to find a consecutive repeat in a string (i.e. [12][12]) but only of length 2 or greater?

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a ="12341234";
        String regex="^(\\d+?)\\1$";
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(a);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

By using the Matcher and the regex above, I get any repeat. However, I only want repeats of size 2 or greater. When I tried doing the regex of

```
^(\\d+?){2,100}\\1$
```

, nothing was returned when I executed the program even though there was a repeat between length 2 and 100. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never say never, but I'm not so sure that this is the sort of problem Regexs are designed to solve. Meanwhile, solving this procedurally is trivial...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is right, you just need to fix a little.  Try this:

```
(\d{2,100})\1
```

I've tested [[here]](https://regex101.com/r/eB9dR5/1)

Update for HSCoder's request :

> make sure that the repeated sequence doesn't have two consecutive
>   numbers that are the same? For example, [11][11] wouldn't work but
>   [12][12] would

Well it's pretty painful to get every two consecutive numbers which are different. Try this :

```
((?:(?=0[^0]|1[^1]|2[^2]|3[^3]|4[^4]|5[^5]|6[^6]|7[^7]|8[^8]|9[^9])\d)+\d)\1
```

I've tested [[here]](https://regex101.com/r/eB9dR5/3)

Comment: It might be worth noting that {2,} will match literally 2 or greater instead of capping at 100 (If that's what you're looking for). `(\d{2,})\1`

Comment: I capped at 100 since I didn't know that leaving nothing after the comma would mean anything greater.

Comment: Also, I forgot to specify... but how would I make sure that the repeated sequence doesn't have two consecutive numbers that are the same? For example, [11][11] wouldn't work but [12][12] would.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```regex
([0-9]{2,})\1+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Find substrings consisting of 2 or more digits that repeat 1 or more times in a row.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/cA5qB7/1

**Sample text**

```
22222
1111
2323
12341234
123123123123
123123123
1
11
1212
14
14
12345
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 0 gets the entire matched string include all the repeats
- Capture group 1 gets the substring that was repeated

```
[0][0] = 2222
[0][1] = 22

[1][0] = 1111
[1][1] = 11

[2][0] = 2323
[2][1] = 23

[3][0] = 12341234
[3][1] = 1234

[4][0] = 123123123123
[4][1] = 123123

[5][0] = 123123123
[5][1] = 123

[6][0] = 1212
[6][1] = 12
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2,}                any character of: '0' to '9' (at least 2
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1+                      what was matched by capture \1 (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```